# Grails: can settings in Config.groovy be overridden programmatically at runtime?

Tags: grails

The mail plugin is [documented](http://gpc.github.io/grails-mail/docs/guide/2.%20Configuration.html) to require its settings in Config.groovy. I want to have it stored in the database so it can be changed at runtime. And this is just one example.

I've read [Does externalizing sensitive config variables into a .properties outside of Config.groovy provide a security advantage in Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137987/does-externalizing-sensitive-config-variables-into-a-properties-outside-of-conf) but this is about using an external property file, I need to store the settings in the database (the app has an admin interface, with auditing and so on).

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properties in the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947021/properties-in-the-database)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `Bootstrap.groovy` you can read the property values from the database and replace those read from the config files by updating `grailsApplication.config`. For example, assume you want to replace the value of a config property named `foo.bar`

```
class BootStrap {

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->

        def fooBarDB = // read the value of foo.bar from the database
        grailsApplication.config.foo.bar = fooBarDB
    }
}
```

Rather than writing this code yourself, you could instead use the [Dynamic Config Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-config) to achieve the same outcome.

Comment: Is it possible to do it outside Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this. During the grails bootstrap process using `Bootstrap.groovy`, retrieve the properties from the database and override them. It's similar to a properties file override, you're just storing them in a database.

Also see [Properties in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947021/properties-in-the-database/)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is the same as Don's, but he was ahead with a few minutes.

Comment: I don't really care who gets the accept since the goal is to provide hlep, but I think you should re-check the times...

Comment: Is it possible to do it outside Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

**First way to change value dynamic:**

```
grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.put("port",your database fetch value of port)
grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.put("username","your database fetch value of username")
grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.put("password","your database fetch value of username")
grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.put("props","your database fetch value of username")
```

**second way to change value dynamic:**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication
```

DefaultGrailsApplication class provide the all the information about config. you can get email information using following code and change it dynamic.

```
def defaultGrailsApplication= new DefaultGrailsApplication()

// to get mails information from Config.groovy
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.get("host")
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.get("port")
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.get("username")
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.get("password")
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.get("props")


// to change mails information of Config.groovy
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.put("host","your database fetch value of host")
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.put("port",your database fetch value of port)
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.put("username","your database fetch value of username")
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.put("password","your database fetch value of username")
defaultGrailsApplication?.config?.grails.mail?.put("props","your database fetch value of username")
```

Now you need to assign this **"defaultGrailsApplication"** instance to inject value of application. just assume that we have one class service Temp.service having grailsApplication injected like:

```
Temp.service

class Temp{
  def grailsApplication

  def your method(){
         please add above code for set value
         grailsApplication = defaultGrailsApplication
  }
```

}

Comment: First way does not works for me ... at least outside bootstrap ... does it worked for you?